# Knockout Components with AMD

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I created a  component in knockout and invoked it using RequireJs, I then tried to make the component a stand alone component and removed the template from my view and created a separate HTML file for the template.
This is the code to register the component

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Knockout")
<script src="~/boot/require.config.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>


<script>
    var dashBoarViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
    ko.components.register('user-details', {
        require: '../koModules/UserdashBoard/Proworldz.dashBoardHeader.js'
    });
    ko.applyBindings(dashBoarViewModel);
</script>
```

In my require.config.js file I have created a require object that provides the dependent text.js file which is required by RequirJs to load HTML templates.
This is how it looks like -

```
    var require = {
        baseUrl: "/",
     paths: {
    "text": "Scripts/text"
             }
         }
```

This is how the Proworldz.dashBoardHeader.js component looks -

```
         define(['text!module/Proworldz.dashBoardHeaderTemplate.html'],function(temp) {
               function MyComponentViewModel(params) {
               this.UserItem = params;
        }

         return {
            viewModel: MyComponentViewModel,
            template: temp 
}
});
```

If I try to remove this config file and directly invoke the text.js file like this

```
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Knockout")
<script src="~/Scripts/text.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>


<script>
    var dashBoarViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
    ko.components.register('user-details', {
        require: '../koModules/UserdashBoard/Proworldz.dashBoardHeader.js'
    });
    ko.applyBindings(dashBoarViewModel);
</script>
```

The template does not get's invoked and gives an error

Uncaught Error: Script error for: text
          http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterrormakeError @                     require.js:166context.onScriptError @ require.js:1701
          require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules:    text!../koModules/UserdashBoard/Proworldz.dashBoardHeaderTemplate.html_unnormalized2

Is it mandatory to create the require object and invoke the text.js file ?Can't I load the text.js file directly ?

Comment: Try removing the '.js' from in '../koModules/UserdashBoard/Proworldz.dashBoardHeader.js' in your component registration.

Comment: No that did not made any difference . I am still not sure about the difference between including the text.js directly and by adding a require object.